# Using Power Query to extract data from nested arrays in JSON

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm relatively new to Power Query, but I'm pulling in this basic structure of JSON from a web api

```
{
    "report": "Cost History",
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "time": [
                {
                    "name": "2019-11",
                    "label": "2019-11",
                    …
                },
                {
                    "name": "2019-12",
                    "label": "2019-12",
                    …
                },
                {
                    "name": "2020-01",
                    "label": "2020-01",
                    …

                },

                …
            ]
        },
        {
            "Category": [
                {
                    "name": "category1",
                    "label": "Category 1",
            …
                },
                {
                    "name": "category2",
                    "label": "Category 2",
            …
                },
                …
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            [
                40419.6393798211
            ],
            [
                191.44
            ],
            …
        ],
        [
            [
                2299.652439184997
            ],
            [
                0.0
            ],
            …
     ]
    ]
}
```

I actually have 112 categories and 13 "times".  I figured out how to do multiple queries to turn the times into column headers and the categories into row labels (I think).  But the data section is alluding me.  Because each item is a list within a list I'm not sure how to expand it all out.  Each object in the date array will have 112 numbers and there will be 13 objects.  If that all makes sense.

So ultimately I want to make it look like

```
            2019-11 2019-20 2020-01 ...
Category 1  40419   2299
Category 2  191     0
...
```

First time asking a question on here, so hopefully this all makes sense and is clear.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i am also researching this exact thing and looking for a solution.  In PQ, it displays nested arrays as a list and there is a function to extract values choosing a separating character[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3FpE.png)

So this becomes, this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJZeD.png)

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {"aligned_to_ids", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})

However the problem i'm trying to solve is when the nested json has multiple values like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4nEE.png)

And when these LIST are extracted then an error message is caused, = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values1", {"collaborators", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text.
Details:
Value=
id=15890
goal_id=323
role_id=15
Type=[Type]

It seems the multiple values are not handled and PQ does not recognise the underlying structure to enable the columns to be expanded.

Comment: So there are Records and Lists, records allow us to select and expand each column by a check list. My issue seems to be cause by the nesting, PQ is interpreting the data as a list but it needs to be transformed into a record, but how to do that? The JSON looks like this:                                                                                                       
 "collaborators": [
{
"id": 27099,
"goal_id": 738,
"role_id": 1399
},
{
"id": 25024,
"goal_id": 738,
"role_id": 1517
},
],

Comment: Ah, so if i expand to rows then it changes from LIST to RECORD and lets me select the columns as required however this has the effect of repeating every row but group and count distinct.  I guess what I'm looking for is a method to create a comma separated values of a single column from an array without having to duplicate lines, is that possible?